# Convert JSON data into excel sheet in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, excel, typescript, file

I need to convert JSON data into an excel sheet using TypeScript.

I want to convert the below data into `.xlsx file`

```
const JsonData = [
  {
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "industry":"IT",
  "role": "Developer",
  "firstName": "Shubham",
  "lastName": "Verma",
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "country": "India"
  },
  {
  "email": "XYG@gmail.com",
  "industry":"IT",
  "role": "Developer",
  "firstName": "Ankit",
  "lastName": "Kumar",
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "country": "India"
  }
]
```

**I explored the internet and StackOverflow but couldn't find the correct and exact solution. That's why asked here. There are lots of solutions for Nodejs and javaScript but not for TypeScript**

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I create the example.xlsx file using JSON data.**

```
const { readFile, writeFile } = require('fs').promises;
const { json2csvAsync } = require('json-2-csv');

async function writeCSVFile (fileName, data) {
  await writeFile(fileName, data, 'utf8');
}

export const createExcel = async (fileName = '', dataToWrite: any) => {
  try {
    const data = JSON.parse(dataToWrite)
    const csv = await json2csvAsync(data);
    await writeCSVFile(fileName, csv);
    console.log(`Successfully converted ${fileName}!`);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return [];
  }
}
```

**How to call the function from different file:**

```
    const JsonData = [
      {
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "industry":"IT",
      "role": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Shubham",
      "lastName": "Verma",
      "title": "Software Engineer",
      "country": "India"
      },
      {
      "email": "XYG@gmail.com",
      "industry":"IT",
      "role": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Ankit",
      "lastName": "Kumar",
      "title": "Software Engineer",
      "country": "India"
      }
   ];




 const fileName = 'result.xlsx';
 const fileResult = await createExcel(fileName, JSON.stringify(JsonData));
```